# Side by side two TFT LCDs 1.8'' with ST7735 driver but one acts differently

Tags: arduino-mega

Hardware setup:

- Custom PCB with ATMega 2560
- Working Batch: TFT LCDs 1.8'' with ST7735 driver (Chinese version)
- Bad Batch: TFT LCDs 1.8'' with ST7735 driver (Chinese version)

Library:
From [Adafruit](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-ST7735-Library), latest version (1.7.0)

I've been using those LCDs for years. But, the LCDs I bought lately are not working as they should be.
They look completely identical from outside. I've bought from several different sellers from China just in case. All of them have the same behavior.

I therefore decided to find a software solution rather than trying out all LCDs in Chinese market.
Whatever variant of ST7735s I have (sellers claim they are just ST7735 nothing else), I need to adapt it to my software accordingly.

In order to keep the trial efforts efficient, I only test on the examples given by Adafruit until I proof it works. I share the outcome of the good and bad LCDs for your comparison below.

Any input greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**: A library had been sent by a seller. But, It doesn't look like it is 100% corresponding to ST7735. For example, since @Majenko asked, I add the initialization code from the library;

```
void Lcd_Init(void)
{

//调用一次这些函数，免得编译的时候提示警告
    LCD_CS =1;
    if(LCD_CS==0)
    {
       LCD_WR_REG_DATA(0,0);
       LCD_ShowString(0,0," ");
       LCD_ShowNum(0,0,0,0);
       LCD_Show2Num(0,0,0,0);
       LCD_DrawPoint_big(0,0);
       LCD_DrawRectangle(0,0,0,0);
       Draw_Circle(0,0,0);
     }

    LCD_REST=1;
    delayms(5); 
    LCD_REST=0;
    delayms(5);
    LCD_REST=1;
    LCD_CS=1; 
    delayms(5);
    LCD_CS =0;  //打开片选使能

        LCD_WR_REG(0x11); //Sleep out
    delayms(120); //Delay 120ms
    //------------------------------------ST7735S Frame Rate-----------------------------------------//
    LCD_WR_REG(0xB1);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x05);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x3C);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x3C);
    LCD_WR_REG(0xB2);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x05);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x3C);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x3C);
    LCD_WR_REG(0xB3);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x05);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x3C);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x3C);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x05);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x3C);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x3C);
    //------------------------------------End ST7735S Frame Rate-----------------------------------------//
    LCD_WR_REG(0xB4); //Dot inversion
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x03);
    LCD_WR_REG(0xC0);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x28);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x08);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x04);
    LCD_WR_REG(0xC1);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0XC0);
    LCD_WR_REG(0xC2);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x0D);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x00);
    LCD_WR_REG(0xC3);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x8D);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x2A);
    LCD_WR_REG(0xC4);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x8D);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0xEE);
    //---------------------------------End ST7735S Power Sequence-------------------------------------//
    LCD_WR_REG(0xC5); //VCOM
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x1A);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x36); //MX, MY, RGB mode
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0xC0);
    //------------------------------------ST7735S Gamma Sequence-----------------------------------------//
    LCD_WR_REG(0xE0);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x04);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x22);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x07);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x0A);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x2E);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x30);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x25);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x2A);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x28);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x26);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x2E);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x3A);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x00);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x01);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x03);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x13);
    LCD_WR_REG(0xE1);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x04);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x16);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x06);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x0D);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x2D);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x26);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x23);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x27);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x27);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x25);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x2D);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x3B);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x00);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x01);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x04);
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x13);
    //------------------------------------End ST7735S Gamma Sequence-----------------------------------------//
    LCD_WR_REG(0x3A); //65k mode
    LCD_WR_DATA8(0x05);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x29); //Display on

}
```

Comment: They probably have different panels with different drive requirements.

Comment: @Majenko, yes, indeed. But which one? Million-dollar question. Sellers send me datasheet, drivers, etc. All point to ST7735.

Comment: Of they have sent you code you should compare the startup register settings against your existing code.

Comment: @Majenko, I did the comparison as you asked. There are similarities but differences as well. I also roughly compared to some other driver (`ILI9341`). I still couldn't recognize the driver. Maybe you may know. I edited my post and added that `INIT` code.  All library is a bit long so I didn't add here. If necessary I can. However, as you know that you can't trust the seller if they ever sent me the correct driver or they ever aware of what they sell.

Comment: The problem is that a TFT is made up of two parts: the controller chip, and the panel. The chip has to be configured by software to drive the panel in the right way. You can have the same chip on many different panels, and a library for one won't work right with another. I can check over the init code later on.

Comment: I think I see the difference. You have a library for the ST7735, but these new ones are in fact the ST7735S - a very different (though confusingly named) chip that needs a different library. Adafruit don't appear to have one, so you will have to find one by someone else.

Comment: @Majenko, I think so too. Either I will try to find one if exists (probably) or I will give a chance to the one given by the seller and try to convert it into Ardunio library. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: It's the init routine that needs replacing in the Adafruit library. It should be easy enough to port.

Comment: I replaced the INIT as per the code I mentioned in my post. But all I get a white background.

Comment: I've just ordered one on eBay from China. It'll take a few weeks to arrive....

Comment: As a backup plan, I've asked my Chinese PCB manufacturer to look for ST7735R versions locally. So, at least I might save the day while I am still working on an S version. I guess, you want to also make a library for everyone's sake, that would be great. I searched many resource centers like github. I am sure somebody already made one but many of them claim their library is for ST7735S but if you look at closely, it is still calling `initR` from Adafruit library. I guess, not many people aware of that S variant. Since that LCDs have no `MISO` (no read), you can't query the version of the LCD :(

Comment: I had asked my PCB manufacturer for looking bare display without back-plane a few days ago and told them that If they can find one and it works OK, I can design a back-plane for it and you make. Guess what, they found one. But strange thing is that the one they bought is -S version (claimed so) and they tested with my PBC and it worked. This is crazy. I am puzzled, I don't know what to say.

Comment: My supplier only does the -S version now (https://www.buydisplay.com/tft-display/tft-display-panel?cotroller_ic=883) so I guess the old non-S one has been discontinued. The -S variant is more capable anyway.

Comment: My TFT has just arrived. I'm going to spend today setting it up and getting it going. I'll report back later.

Comment: Ok, this is strange. Mine works straight out of the box. The PCB is a little different to yours, but it's supposedly an St7735S chip. Like yours it's a "green tab" variant panel, but I don't tell it to use the green tab init, just the default black tab, which works fine (the green tab init just adds an offset to the display).

Comment: You are lucky then. I didn't take my chance this time and I made a back-plane design and it is going to be manufactured next week for bare LCD. I purchased the bare LCDs. My fab will assemble them. At least that way I could also add some TVS for the SPI lines. Last time, during EMC tests the LCD was failed.

Comment: However, you said that Adafruit has not the ST7735S library. Have you made one yourself? If it is so, would you like to share for the Arduino community somewhere reachable?

Comment: No, it's just the stock adafruit library - when I started experimenting and looking at the examples I saw they have the `.initR()` function for selecting the variant: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-ST7735-Library/blob/master/examples/graphicstest/graphicstest.ino#L87